# What is the Difference between Displacement Node Normal Node and displace modifier?

Tags: modifiers, node-editor, geometry, displacement

The Displacement node doesn't seem to be much different than a normal map, where as the displacement modifier will actually effect the geometry.  Am I missing something here, is there a difference in the node tree between normal mapping and displacement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Displacement modifier: affect geometry directly

Normal map: affects polygons perceived orientation in regard to how they reacts to light

Displacement node: affect geometry when rendered (need to be rendering with cycles and turn on displacement in material settings)

Comment: Ok so displacement in the node tree you wont see in the viewport, just in cycles.  Does displacement in the node tree work with Eevee?

Comment: Correct (Cycles preview in viewport works though). Eevee doesn't support displacement yet.